# How to delete object in object by criteria

Tags: javascript, object

I have this:

```
Object {1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object, 9: Object, 10: Object, 11: Object, 12: Object, 13: Object, 14: Object, 15: Object}1: Object2: Object3: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object__proto__: Object4: Object1: Object2: ObjectfromLevel: "1"toLevel: "6"__proto__: Object3: Object4: Object5: ObjectfromLevel: "1"toLevel: "6"__proto__: Object__proto__: Object5: Object6: Object1: Object2: Object3: ObjectfromLevel: "1"toLevel: "6"__proto__: Object4: Object5: Object__proto__: Object7: Object8: Object9: Object10: Object11: Object12: Object1: Object2: ObjectfromLevel: undefinedtoLevel: undefined__proto__: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object__proto__: Object13: Object14: Object15: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: ObjectfromLevel: undefinedtoLevel: undefined__proto__: Object5: Object6: Object7: Object8: Object9: Object10: Object11: Object12: Object13: Object14: Object15: Object16: Object17: Object18: Object__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
```

I need to remove each object that has undefined properties. 
And if there isn't any child objects in the parent object, then i need to delete this parent object.
In other words i need to have only objects that has properties not equals to undefined.

Comment: Did you really need to include all that object structure in a single line? Couldn't a much smaller and formatted object also work in making your point?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: please add a valid object.

Comment: ` var JObj = new Object();
        
        $.each($("ol"), function(n){
     if (!JObj.hasOwnProperty($(this).attr("table"))) {
         JObj[$(this).attr("table")] = new Object();
     }
     if (!JObj[$(this).attr("table")].hasOwnProperty($(this).attr("column"))) {
         JObj[$(this).attr("table")][$(this).attr("column")] = new Object();
     }
     JObj[$(this).attr("table")][$(this).attr("column")].fromLevel = $(this).find('.ui-selected:last').attr("row");
     JObj[$(this).attr("table")][$(this).attr("column")].toLevel = $(this).find('.ui-selected:first').attr("row");`

Comment: That is my code for adding items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/qmnz6w61/

```
var topObject = {
    x: {},
    y: undefined,
    z: {
        n: 11,
        c: undefined,
        o: {
            a: undefined,
            l: 44
        }
    }
};

function checkObject (obj) {
    // Loop through obj key and check them
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // Key value equals undefined, then delete it.
            if(obj[key] === undefined) {
                delete obj[key];
            } 

            // Check this child if it is an object
            else if(obj[key].constructor === Object) {
                checkObject(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to delete the empty objects as well, use this check:

```
JSON.stringify(obj[key]) === '{}' // true if obj[key] is empty object
```

Comment: @Viruscom1000 Welcome!